# Sliding menu gesture overwrites the scrollable gesture of a graph gesture-android

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, scrollable, sliding

I am using a sliding menu from [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my application. My app also has a [GraphView](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html) in which I set some data in real time. The graph is a linear graph which is scrollable, to the left and to the right. But, having the sliding menu by a left to right gesture, the user cannot scroll in the graph because the menu keeps popping out.

Is there any way I can overwrite the menu functionality when a certain item is pressed? The graph item is just a LinearLayout.

I am also using fragments, so each menu item is a fragment.

Comment: Sliding menu can be configured to open when dragged from extreme side. I think enable that configuration and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didnt know I could do that. It worked like a charm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you call

```
setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
```

and not

```
setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

On your SlidingMenu object/fragment/activity so that the menu shows only when you drag it from the edge/bezel of your screen

Comment: Thanks, thats like the easiest and most convenient solution. Exactly what I wanted